# beautiful soup extract cell but keep format

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

everyone:

I am new to beautiful soup, working on parse table, i was able to get to cell level. Let's say cell is something I am trying to extract...

I know type(cell) is 
I know cell content is

```
<td> Raptors v. Jazz <b>UNDER 196</b> </td>
```

When I do cell.text, i get

**output:**
Raptors v. Jazz UNDER 196

But what I truly want to get is

**expected output:**
**Raptors v. Jazz **UNDER 196****
because item inside  is the winning team....

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `decode_contents`:

```
>>> td.decode_contents()
' Raptors v. Jazz <b>UNDER 196</b> '
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's play some trick on `extract()`

> PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree.

example:

```
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's <i>story</i></b></p>
....
```

if you simply use `extract()` on target tag, you get

```
>> soup.find('p', {"class": "title"}).extract()
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's <i>story</i></b></p>
```

but if you extract the `.next` element on the tag, you get

```
>> soup.find('p', {"class": "title"}).next.extract()
<b>The Dormouse's <i>story</i></b>
```

Comment: `decode_contents()` seems a better way to get the result, which `Renders the contents of this tag as a Unicode string.` and won't modify the DOM.